# How to show large text without "Font size too large to fit in cache" and not broken shared-element transition

Tags: android, font-size, hardware-acceleration, shared-element-transition

I have shared element transition for TextView with some text. Text size changes from 25sp to 200sp.

If text contains colored Emoji (☺) I get "Font size too large to fit in cache".

As I know there is android property "ro.hwui.text_large_cache_height" which determine max height of gliph texture, but it is not equal textSize, so I don't know how I can use it.

When I set textview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) - this solve the problem with showing text, but broke the transition - text appears only at the end.

How could it be fixed? Thanks.